# Increasing Requests Per Seconds in Gatling

Tags: gatling

I'm trying to increase Requests Per Second in Gatling with fewer Users (Each User-created will send API requests in a loop). I achieved 300 RPS with 35 Users. However, even if I increase the users to 70 or 150, I cannot get a higher rps than 300. With increased user count, the RPS is more than 300 for the initial few seconds but later just hovers around 300.

I tried both atOnceUsers and rampUsers, but still couldn't achieve higher RPS.

Is there any way to increase RPS with fewer​ users?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out where your constraint is - look at the results coming back from the simulation and examine how the response time changes with the number of requests. You may be being throttled by your application under test

Comment: Thanks James.  when I increased the atOnceUsers count from 75 to 150 the mean changed from 299 to 493 Ms. Also, my Application handled ConstanstUsersPerSec of 240 (RPS of 240), 300 (RPS of 280) without any issues. Is there any way to identify that the application is throttling?

Comment: there are tons of potential spots. Check things like cpu / memory / network stats. Look at the db performance and query execution time.

Comment: the Db Performance and query execution times (around 60 milliseconds) look good. I couldn't get the CPU/memory/network stats of the container where my Gatling tests are running. I use Gatling with sbt. are there any restrictions around it limiting the throttle?